# A given column is not a column of the data frame

Tags: python, model, pipeline, knn, model-fitting

I am trying to create a KNN model and after creating and trying to fit the model, but it gives this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3803             except KeyError as err:

12 frames pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'BP_list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) KeyError: 'BP_list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in
_get_column_indices(X, key)
    454 
    455         except KeyError as e:
--> 456             raise ValueError("A given column is not a column of the dataframe") from e
    457 
    458         return column_indices

ValueError: A given column is not a column of the dataframe
```

[image: error description]

I tried changing the columns but that didn't work.